# Multidimensional Array in Javascript from a parsed JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I want to take this JSON data array obj:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
if (obj.status === "error") {
       alert(obj.message);
} else {
       $.each(obj.data, function (index, value) {
```

And then copy the data into another array to be able to then query along an index. The data is from a API call from a SQL database. However the index from the API call might not be in a consecutive order and therefore I need to move up and down the array via a stepping of 1. So ideally I want to be able to get `obj[i].id` where i is the array index and each index holds a array of data copied from the JSON obj array such as:

```
id
URL
description
```

Hope this makes sense. I'm sure I have done this in other Javascripts but I seem to be having a problem with the JSON one.

The JSON recieved is similar to:

```
{"status" : "success", "data" : [{"id":"8", "url":"http:\/\/google.com", "description":"Search Engine"}, {"id":"12", "url":"http:\/\/google.co.uk", "description":"Search Engine UK"}] }
```

So I would like this to become in an array:

```
obj[0].id === 1
obj[0].url === "http://google.com"
obj[0].description === "Search Engine"
obj[1].id === 5
obj[1].url === "http://google.co.uk"
obj[1].description === "Search Engine UK"
```

This way i can step up and down the array. Or is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks

Ed

Comment: @Cristoph made the same edit :'D

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to achieve. You can already access your objects with bracket notation as arrays. Can you add in your post also what is the output you would like please?

Comment: "The JSON recieved is " … invalid JSON. You need to fix it before you can parse it.

Comment: Ignore the formatting. Assume it's correct (because it is in the real version). The point is how do I take a JSON lump of arrays and put them into a multidimensional array I can move up and down ? I have looked through all my books and websites and they only reference single column arrays. WHen i try to do what I think would be correct and works in other languages it fails.

Comment: Please, update your question with your valid JSON.

Comment: can you please follow the suggestion to have a valid JSON? with a valid JSON your data property will be already an array and you can already do what you want to

Comment: *Ignore the formatting. Assume it's correct* but it's not. And it'll be really hard to give you a relevant answer when we have no idea what the source actually looks like.

Comment: but "formatting issue" is one thing. Data structure issue is another.

Comment: OK here is the source.Sorry I'm working at a remote location so was hard to get but managed to get a copy.

Comment: `var myArrayOfObjects = response.data;` ?

Comment: Why does the first ID change from `8` to `1`?

Comment: `obj.data` already appears to be in the format that you want it. The result you're asking for is not a multi-dimensional array, it's an array of objects, and that's what `obj.data` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `for` loop for this, like so:

```
for (let object of obj.data) {
    console.log(object.id)
}
```

This will print the `id` of every object in the parsed JSON. Obviously, you can also print other attributes, or do whatever you want to do with the object.

Comment: of? Did I miss some new keyword? 
Btw obj.data is already an array of objects

Comment: `for ... of` works like Python's `for`. It iterates through your iterable and returns a reference to the object, unlike `for ... in` that returns that object's index. According to the documentation it's available in most browsers already, so compatibility shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: oh cool, I missed the of in the loops in JavaScript thanks. I am completely used to `forEach`, it's a while I didn't use a plain for

Comment: You should probably use `for ... of` when possible. It's significantly more performant than `forEach`.

Comment: I do use for when I am doing something relative for performances. But when I am looking for readability and compactness of the code, I do prefer the forEach. Btw thanks for letting me know about the of, I was aware only of the in for JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

To go from a JS object to an array, you can use:

```
var arrayFromObj = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k]; });
```

which will give you an array of the values in the object.

However it's not really clear if this is what you want from your question - as @quirimmo has commented, you may already have the data you want in `obj.data` ?

Comment: So the obj.data has the data part of the JSON response. So when it iterates using the $.each function you can call the different fields like value.id or value.description. What I want is to go  down that array to a specific point such as obj.data[0].value.id if that makes sense....

Comment: his object.data is already an array. Why are you converting it?  :'(
@Mako77 you can already do with your response the `response.data[0].id`

Comment: OK I will try again and post an update. I did try this and it didn't work. I'll do it again in an hour. I might have called obj[0].data.id which wouldn't make any sense but that's the only mistake I could have made. Will let you know.

Comment: So this worked. I must have put the [] in the wrong place. However how would I now find the size of that array? I tried obj.data.length to no avail.